# Why is Dijkstra's Algorithm more popular compared to Grassfire algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, time-complexity, shortest-path, greedy-algorithms

Consider algorithms to find shortest paths in a graph. The grassfire algorithm has a complexity of `O(|V|)` where `V` is the number of nodes or vertices. The Dijkstra's algorithm has a complexity of `O((|V| + |E|) * log(|V|))` where `E` is the number of edges. Compared to A star, the Dijkstra's does not rely on properties of any heuristic which makes them popular. But I am trying to understand the advantage of Dijkstra's over Grassfire. Are there practical reasons why this is the case? Or am I simply seeing more cases of Dijkstra's compared to Grassfire due to the application areas such as navigation that I am working on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In grassfire the distances are constant. All of your neighbors have equal length. In a weighted graph, grassfire will fail.

Graphfire is actually based on a small modification of BFS.

The Dijsktra works on weighted graphs, too.

**Note:** If all costs are equal, Dijkstra = BFS

Know the difference, and use them according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

The Grassfire algorithm only works on a particular kind of graph; Dijkstra's algorithm works on any graph.