# Grassfire vs BFS

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, search-algorithms

Expanding on this question :

[Why is Dijkstra's Algorithm more popular compared to Grassfire algorithm?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/98516/why-is-dijkstras-algorithm-more-popular-compared-to-grassfire-algorithm)

What are the differences between grassfire and BFS? I'm surprised grassfire (supposedly) has a complexity of only $O(|V|)$, whereas BFS has a complexity of $O(|V| + |E|)$.

Comment: Quoting the answer to the linked question, "In grassfire the distances are constant."

Comment: @Yuval Filmus The distances in BFS are constant as well.

Comment: "Grassfire is actually based on a small modification of BFS."

Comment: @Yuval Filmus I can read

Comment: Grassfire runs in time $O(|V|)$ since a 2D grid has $|E| = \Theta(|V|)$. Grassfire (as described on Wikipedia) has only two passes, whereas BFS can have many iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grassfire seems to be simply a BFS in a 2D grid graph. Since $|E| = \Theta(|V|)$ in a 2D grid graph, this results in a complexity of $O(|V| + |E|) = O(|V|)$.

See also Wikipedia's page on the similar grassfire transform (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassfire_transform), a computation of the distance from some pixel(s) to the border of a region in an image, which can be used to yield descriptors such as the region's skeleton or medial axis.